# 2 column layout HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created following html layout.

```
<div class="main-section">

   <div class="column-one">Column left</div>
   <div class="column-two">Column left</div>

   <div class="column-three">Column right</div>
</div>
```

I want to create 2 column section like below:

```
------------------------------------
|              |                   |
| Column One   |   Column Three    |
| Column Two   |                   |
------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to make like this? Only for CSS, Not need to js or jquery.
Also we need to achive this without change html layout.
Use only css for this.

It is not similar question with another.

Comment: this can be done with flex but you would need to wrap columns 1 & 2 in a parent wrapper then apply flex to that  and column 3

Comment: You can use the `display:grid` to achieve this and without any JQuery or JavaScript

Comment: Could you post what you found while doing the research regarding this?

Comment: You can add something like this (CSS):

div.main-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

div.column-one, div.column-two {
  grid-column: 1;
}

div.column-three {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1/ span 2;
}

Comment: no more difficult than: `.main-section { column-count: 2; column-width: 50% }`

Comment: "It is not similar question with another"—how is it different from the marked duplicate? You need to justify comments like this.